# Jquery replace only specific characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace all special characters except #-. But below code allows all special characters after typing of above mentioned.

```
 $("[id='searchjobautotop']").keyup(function(e){
            var start = this.selectionStart,
            end = this.selectionEnd;
            var data= $(this).val() ;
            var dataFull = data.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z#.- ]/g, '');
            if(e.which!=37 && e.which!=39 && data.length<2)
            $(this).val(dataFull);
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);

         });
```

Please make a JSFIDDLE sample for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a Coding service

Comment: what is it then?

Comment: I've just asked a question.

Comment: So, why don't you remove the characters you do not want to replace from your regex?

Comment: @FaisalShahzad Stack Overflow is a place where you can get help fixing the error you have in your code. That means you have to try something yourself first

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I've tried it. then I posted it here. question is: this code let's pass all other special characters after typing the # sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("[id='searchjobautotop']").keyup(function(e) {
             var start = this.selectionStart,
                 end = this.selectionEnd;
             var data = $(this).val();
             var dataFull = data.replace(/([~!@$%^&*()+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,\/? ])+/g, '');
             if (e.which != 37 && e.which != 39)
                 $(this).val(dataFull);
             this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
             });
```

This worked for me!